# enable a MDI child form from another MDI Child

Tags: vb.net

I have a parent form that opens a frmMDIChild1. frmMDChild1 opens frmMDIChild2 and when it does it also runs this.

```
Dim newMDIChild As New Customer_Order()
Me.Enabled = False
newMDIChild.TopLevel = False
newMDIChild.Parent = frmMain
newMDIChild.MinimizeBox = False
newMDIChild.MaximizeBox = False
newMDIChild.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow
newMDIChild.Show()
```

I want to be able to re-enaable frmMDIChild1 when I click the close button on frmMDIChild2 however when I tried

```
frmMDIChild1.enabled = true
```

it doesn't do anything.

Comment: You are using inappropriate identifier names, this doesn't have anything to do with MDI.  By setting TopLevel = false, you turned the form into a client control.  If now behaves just like a UserControl.  You probably noticed that it doesn't behave normally but changing the FormBorderStyle to a tool window isn't enough, only None is appropriate.  And it doesn't generate events like FormClosed anymore of course so you can't tell when the user clicked the dummy close button.  If you want an MDI child window then don't do this.

Comment: Even if I added my own button command to close the form I wouldn't be able to have it send frmMDIChild1.enabled = true to that form?